# Does the "force-sensitive" question need to be limited somehow?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[How to limit the proportion of a Force sensitive population?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/74694/how-to-limit-the-proportion-of-a-force-sensitive-population) was asked 16 hours ago and already has 17 answers, all score 0 or higher.  The question lays out an interesting problem and describes some approaches that don't work for the OP, which are things we want to see in questions, and then asks for a solution that's not one of those.  Apparently there are still lots of approaches, and on a quick read we don't have a big pile of non-answers or poor answers.  It's just...broad.

Unlike many of our overly-broad questions, this one shows a decent amount of effort.  It's not one of those "I have this vague idea -- what would happen?" questions that we sometimes get.  The question does involve magic (the force).

What if anything should we do with the question and/or its answers?  Is there some problem in the question that ought to be addressed, or is this just what happens when magic is involved?  Do we need better guidelines and, if so, which ones?

Comment: One problem I see that you have not addressed is that the author invalidated existing answers with edits. [The caste system](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/74696/28789) was ruled out by an revision 3 as well as the highest ranking answer the [reduced fertility](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/74697/28789). Other than that the answers seem to be acceptable overall. The question looks broad but it is okay now with the edits the OP made.

Comment: @Secespitus oh, thanks -- I didn't review the edit history.

Answer (score 3):

In this specific case I would leave it as is, it doesn't seem to be causing any significant issues yet.

More broadly I'm thinking that the nature of world building being what it is, a largely imaginative process where most things are possible, this is simply to be expected. Looking around it seems that most popular questions receive more than a handful of pretty good answers, and in most cases you can separate the sand from the pearls by waiting for the votes to roll in.

In my mind this should be more of a voting culture issue than a guidance or closevote issue. Let people downvote questions they feel are pushing the line and upvote when they feel the question has merit. Similarly people shouldn't shy away from downvoting the 18th answer that doesn't add much.

I've seen this sort of thing on more concrete sites like Stackoverflow as well, sometimes there really are more than a dozen perfectly acceptable ways to do the same thing.

Comment: I think we don't (in aggregate) downvote enough, and downvotes are an important part of the signal on questions with bunches of answers.  Sometimes we see multiple flags on answers without a single downvote.  We also need to remember that 20k users, who can vote to delete, can only do so on answers with negative scores.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, and I am new, I think that 'world-building' is always going to entail some questions regarding trans-empirical physics - i.e., physics-building / universal-rules-building, and that is okay too.